# How to use daisyui 4.7.3 with Nuxt3

Tags: nuxt.js, daisyui

When trying to implement daisyui 4.7.3 in Nuxt3 the theme colors are not changing when changing the theme.

The Stackblitz I created is: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-color-mode-daisyui-qgpvqe

You can change the theme on the left upper corner.

it is based on this Stackblitz which is using daisy 2.42 https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-color-mode-daisyui-snrnt9

the 2.42 Version is working fine.

Comment: The themes are working fine from what I can see on the reproduction.

Comment: Right, now it's working. I was modifying it, added the themes list to the tailwind.config.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution myself:
in tailwind.config.js it is necessary to add the themes like:

```
module.exports = {
plugins: [require('daisyui')],
daisyui: {
  themes: [
    'system',
    'light',
    'dark',
    'cupcake',
    'bumblebee',
    'emerald',
    'corporate',
    'synthwave',
    'retro',
    'cyberpunk',
    'valentine',
    'halloween',
    'garden',
    'forest',
    'aqua',
    'lofi',
    'pastel',
    'fantasy',
    'wireframe',
    'black',
    'luxury',
    'dracula',
    'cmyk',
    'autumn',
    'business',
    'acid',
    'lemonade',
    'night',
    'coffee',
    'winter',
  ],
},
```

};

Seems like this was not necessary in the 2.42 version. At least in the Stackblitz I provided, there were no themes listed.

Comment: Probably for performance reasons. Feel free to accept your own answer.